# Dynamic Exchange Rate using DAX

Tags: dax

I want to get my amount to change as per currency code selected dynamically.

In my FactSales table I have currency and Amount. If user want to see that amount in any currency he select the currency from slicer and my excahnge rate will apply to that amount.

I tried below DAX to get dynamic Exchange Rate but no luck:

```
ExchangeRate = CALCULATE(MIN(ExchangeRate[ExcahngeRate]), FILTER(ExchangeRate, AND(AND(AND(MIN(FactSales[TransDate])>=MIN(ExchangeRate[ValidFrom]), MIN(FactSales[TransDate])<=IF(ISBLANK(MIN(ExchangeRate[ValidTo])), DATEVALUE("01-01-2070"), MIN(ExchangeRate[ValidTo]))), MIN(ExchangeRate[FromCurrencyCode]) = MIN(FactSales[CurrencyCode])), MIN(ExchangeRate[ToCurrencyCode]) = FIRSTNONBLANK(ExchangeRate[ToCurrencyCode],1))))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Able to write DAX myself:`ExchangeRate = 
CALCULATE(MIN(ExchangeRate[ExcahngeRate]), 
  FILTER(FILTER(ExchangeRate, AND(AND(ExchangeRate[FromCurrencyCode] = MIN(FactSales[TransactionCurrencyCode])
  , ExchangeRate[ToCurrencyCode] = FIRSTNONBLANK(ExchangeRate[ToCurrencyCode],1))
  , MIN(FactSales[TransDate])<=IF(ISBLANK(ExchangeRate[ValidTo].[Date]), DATEVALUE("2070-01-01"), ExchangeRate[ValidTo])))
  , MIN(FactSales[TransDate])>= ExchangeRate[ValidFrom]))`

Answer (score 0):

If we have Exchange rate on daily basis then we can go for below solution:

[enter link description here](https://www.kasperonbi.com/currency-conversion-in-dax-for-power-bi-and-ssas/):https://www.kasperonbi.com/currency-conversion-in-dax-for-power-bi-and-ssas/

[image]

If we have Exchange Rate as date range then use dynamic DAX:
`ExchangeRate = 
IF(ISBLANK
    (
        CALCULATE(MIN(ExchangeRate[ExcahngeRate]), 
        FILTER(FILTER(ExchangeRate, AND(AND(ExchangeRate[FromCurrencyCode] = MIN(FactSales[TransactionCurrencyCode]), ExchangeRate[ToCurrencyCode] = FIRSTNONBLANK(ExchangeRate[ToCurrencyCode],1))
        , MIN(FactSales[TransDate])<=IF(ISBLANK(ExchangeRate[ValidTo].[Date]), DATEVALUE("2070-01-01"), ExchangeRate[ValidTo]))), MIN(FactSales[TransDate])>= ExchangeRate[ValidFrom]))
    )
    , 1
    , CALCULATE(MIN(ExchangeRate[ExcahngeRate]), 
        FILTER(FILTER(ExchangeRate, AND(AND(ExchangeRate[FromCurrencyCode] = MIN(FactSales[TransactionCurrencyCode])
        , ExchangeRate[ToCurrencyCode] = FIRSTNONBLANK(ExchangeRate[ToCurrencyCode],1))
        , MIN(FactSales[TransDate])<=IF(ISBLANK(ExchangeRate[ValidTo].[Date]), DATEVALUE("2070-01-01"), ExchangeRate[ValidTo])))
        , MIN(FactSales[TransDate])>= ExchangeRate[ValidFrom]))
)`

[image]
[image]